# Can I access a struct by name, eg A = field1, get struct.A?

Tags: struct, julia

Here's a psuedocode implementation of what I would be looking for within Julia:

```
struct Example
    field1::Float64
    field2::Float64
end # End struct 

example = Example(1., 2.)

function modifystruct(mystruct, fieldname)
    mystruct.fieldname +=10
    return mystruct
end 

modifystruct(example, field1)
# In this instance I would want to have example.field1 = 11.
```

How would I actually do this? I want to provide the fieldname as something like a string, and have my struct."whateverfieldname" get modified as such. I should add that I do NOT want to code something in like this:

```
function modifystruct(mystruct, fieldname)
    if fieldname = "fieldname1"
        mystruct.field1 +=10 
    end
    if fieldname = "fieldname2" 
        mystruct.field2 +=10
    end 
    return mystruct
end
```

Largely due to how versatile I want this code to be. I may be using different types of structs for my program, so the closest I can get to directly accessing by the name of the field, the better. Is there any method or implementation that can do this for me?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, that's [`setproperty!(value, name, x)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.setproperty!) and [`getproperty(value, name)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.getproperty):

```
function modifystruct(mystruct, fieldname)
    new_field = getproperty(mystruct, fieldname) + 10
    setproperty!(mystruct, fieldname, new_field)
    return mystruct
end
```

As DecowVR rightly notes, this requires `mystruct` to be mutable.

If you want to do this repeatedly and with nested properties, you might be interested in lenses such as those provided by [Setfield.jl](https://github.com/jw3126/Setfield.jl).

Comment: Also, I would call the first argument `myobject`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, whould be noticed that in order to be able to modify an struct, it needs to be `mutable`:

```
julia> mutable struct Example
           field1::Float64
           field2::Float64
       end

julia> example = Example(1., 2.)
Example(1.0, 2.0)
```

And now, a simple aproach would be to use Julia [Symbols](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/). A symbol is nothing else but an expression like `:var`. Can be used as shown:

```
julia> example.:field1
1.0
```

However, if we create a variable that stores the symbol, it won't work:

```
julia> v = :field1
:field1

julia> example.v
ERROR: type Example has no field v
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(x::Example, f::Symbol)
   @ Base ./Base.jl:42
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[18]:1
```

This is due to the order in which the Julia Interpreter works. If we want to evaluate firstly the variable, and then the expression, it is as easy as:

```
julia> @eval example.$v
1.0
```

So the complete function would be as follows:

```
julia> function modify_struct(mystruct::Example, fieldname::Symbol)
           @eval $mystruct.$fieldname += 10
       end
```

Comment: Not wrong, but `eval` is really overkill for what is needed.

Comment: and you should avoid `eval` unless really necessary